# Figure out the last day (in LocalDate) of a YearMonth instance - joda library

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a `YearMonth` instance, is there an easy way to figure what the last day, in `LocalDate`, of that instance is?

I know there is a `toLocalDate(int day)`, but I may not know if the month has the 31st day or not.
Of course, I can always put the code in a try-catch block and try with `31` first then if that fails, try with `30` (or `29`, or `28` for Feb).

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 1st of the next month, and then subtract one day?

Answer (score 0):

Eiter the answer of  @MartinMilan (a standard algorithm working in most libraries) or following built-in solution of JodaTime-library:

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now();
LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.toLocalDate(1).dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
```